# How to separate values from string using quotes as escape secuence?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

For example: have this text:

```
'Data 1;Data 2;"Da;ta;3;etc...";Data 4'
```

How to separate this into array values like as `Data 1`, `Da;ta;3;etc...`, `Data 4`, etc? have a unknown number of `;` into quotes and have any binary chars into content (non utf-8).

I try using a split:

```
data = line.strip().split(b';')
```

But have a problem with the delimiters into quotes. I try replacing the delimiters using:

```
line = re.sub(rb'(".+?);(.+?")', rb'\1 - \2', line)
```

But the problem is when have two o more delimiters.

Can not use csv module, csv can not support a binary read mode.

Comment: What are you trying to do?. How can you get lowercase `data1` when it is not even  in your input string.

Comment: Try load a simple but big csv and process for each row in binary mode.

Comment: Edited, the concept of the question is understood.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

test_str = 'Data 1;Data 2;"Da;ta;3;etc...";Data 4'
regex = '\"([^\"]+)\"'
data_list = re.findall(regex,test_str)
for data in matches:
    test_str = test_str.replace(f"\"{data}\";","")
data_list = data_list + test_str.split(';')
```

Here data_list would look like this : `['Da;ta;3;etc...', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 4']`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understood correctly, but if you want split your string having `"` as a delimiter it's as simple as:

```
line = 'Data 1;Data 2;"Da;ta;3;etc...";Data 4'
my_array = line.split('"')
```

Which results in the following array:
`['Data 1;Data 2;', 'Da;ta;3;etc...', ';Data 4']`

Now if you want to split both by `"` and `;` you can:

```
line = 'Data 1;Data 2;"Da;ta;3;etc...";Data 4'
my_array = []
for entry in line.split('"'):
    my_array.extend(entry.split(';')) 4']
```

Which results in the following array:
`['Data 1', 'Data 2', '', 'Da', 'ta', '3', 'etc...', '', 'Data 4']`

Comment: Thanks, but the data 3 need as simple value, `Data 1`, `Data 2`, `Da;ta;3;etc...` and `Data 4`.

Comment: Re-reading the question today it seems Anand Joshi's answer does what you want.